# I am not able to log into my azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am not able to login my Azure VM. I have reset the password through azure portal but it is still not logging in. Previously, it used to log in and now it is showing following error :

```
An authentication error has occurred.
```

The function requested is not supported"

I have other VM which are logging in fine as before. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link.

This is due to a combination of three factors:

- You activated NLA on your target computer
- The target computer is not patched for CVE-2018-0886
- You enforced the Force updated clients or Mitigated parameters on the source computer

https://itluke.online/2018/03/29/solved-authentication-error-function-not-supported/